# Some keyboard shortcuts do not work in Compiz

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, compiz

I've bound <kbd>Win-R</kbd> with the *Run Application* dialog in Metacity. However, the shortcut doesn't work when switched to Compiz. The entry *Show the panel's "Run application" dialog box* even doesn't appear in the *Keyboard Shortcuts* dialog in Compiz.

There are also other shortcuts that do not work in Compiz. I can add them using custom shortcuts, but I don't know the command line to popup the "Run Application" dialog.

Why are there so many shortcut entries missing in Compiz? (~90 entries in Metacity compared to ~20 entries in Compiz)

(OS: Debian Squeeze)

**EDIT**

Screenshot: Keyboard shortcuts list in Compiz

[image: Keyboard shortcuts list in Compiz wm]

As you see, the list is very limited, most shortcuts set in Metacity are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu, and for some reason, some of the keyboard shortcuts are configured in "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". There I have the setting for "key to execute a command".

So maybe you should look through all compiz plugins settings.